# Add a column to dataframe from values of next row

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with the below structure and values:

```
total_size <- 5000;
id line_number
1   1232
2   1456
3   1832
4   2002
```

I need to add a new column dynamically to the data frame with values from the next_row. ie:
The new column value should be: (line_number) of next row -1. The value of the last row should be populated with the total_size value.

The final output I need to produce is:

```
id line_number   end_line_number
1   1232         1455
2   1456         1831
3   1832         2001
4   2002         5000
```

Any idea how I can generate this dynamically in R?

Answer (score 6):

This is pretty basic question. You can create a new column by removing the first entry of the 2nd column, subtracting 1 from it and adding NA for the last entry.

```
# assuming your data.frame is called 'dt'
dt$end_line_number <- c(dt$line_number[-1]-1, NA)
```

(or) using `transform`

```
dt <- transform(dt, end_line_number = c(line_number[-1]-1, NA))
```

Comment: Okay Great. Thanks.These work. is there preference of using one approach over the other?

Comment: `transform` allows you to use the column ids without having to do "dt$" every single time. In that sense, I find it much more cleaner. But I guess it's more of a personal preference...

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr` you can use `lead()`. For example

```
library(dplyr)
dd |> 
  mutate(end_line_number=lead(line_number, 1, total_size+1)-1)
#   id line_number end_line_number
# 1  1        1232            1455
# 2  2        1456            1831
# 3  3        1832            2001
# 4  4        2002            5000
```